# redirect to form and select option only on button click - else default to the standard display of nav-tab

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have a form on one nav-tab and I am linking to it from another nav-tab. I link to all of my nav-tabs from several pages using the code below.

```
     const hash=window.location.hash;
        const bsTab = new bootstrap.Tab(hash);
        bsTab.show();
```

it works, but:

1. I would like to remove the hashtag after redirecting from the url if possible. That's one issue I'm having with this portion of my javascript.
2. The Other is: In order to link to my form using a button, I came up with the following solution:

   ```
       function redirectToForm() {
           window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/#nav- 
       contact-me-tab";
           localStorage.setItem("selectedOption", "2");
       }

       const hash=window.location.hash;
       const bsTab = new bootstrap.Tab(hash);
       bsTab.show();

       var selectedOption = 
     localStorage.getItem("selectedOption");
       document.getElementById("reason").value = selectedOption;
       localStorage.removeItem("selectedOption");
   ```

This works at first glance, however, if I end up linking back to the form, the default option is no longer selected. In some cases, no option is selected. I want to always have the form show the default selected option ("0" by default which is disabled otherwise) unless my button is clicked. Only if my button is clicked do I want to change this value to option 2. If i redirect to my form from another link, I want the default disable value to display

This is my button:

```
<button id="gotoformselect2" onclick="redirectToForm()">Request References</button>
```

Maybe someone who knows javascript a little better can:

1. help me remove the hash after redirecting to each nav-tab &
2. can better structure my code to only select option 2 if my button is clicked.

Otherwise, if I link to the form, or any other nav-tab for that matter, I want to only use this code:

```
const hash=window.location.hash;
        const bsTab = new bootstrap.Tab(hash);
        bsTab.show();
```

Let me know if you can help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use **history API** to replace the hash.
2. Use selectedIndex to select for dropdown option.

```
function redirectToForm() {
  window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/#nav-contact-me-tab";
  localStorage.setItem("selectedOption", "2");
}

if (location.hash) {
  const hash = location.hash;
  const bsTab = new bootstrap.Tab(hash);
  bsTab.show();
  history.replaceState('', null, location.origin+location.pathname); //replaces the hash
}

if (localStorage.getItem('selectedOption')) {
  const option = localStorage.getItem('selectedOption');
  document.getElementById('reason').selectedIndex = option;
  localStorage.removeItem("selectedOption");
}
```

Comment: So, I discovered that if I click a footer link to another page, also with navtabs that this code then changes the url to the base url from which I am clicking from. I want it to show the full URL minus the hash of whatever page I visit. Currently, when I'm on another page, the url does not show the correct page.  @Yuvaraj M

Comment: @TheDigitalGuru, i changed the code. Now the url minus hash rule applied

Comment: Happy codding :)

Comment: I apologize my friend, but I am trying to stay on the same nav-tab as my form, upon submission. This way I can view the success or error message being output. I've tried a few things using javascript to do this, but believe the code you provided above, removing the hash and what not, might be affecting this. I have like three more inquiries to finalize this project, but will sort the remaining two out elsewhere as you've been so helpful already. But can you provide how I can submit my form from my nav-tab and be brought back to the same nav-tab despite our code above in php or js

Comment: I tried this but had no luck: 
$(function () {
  var tabName = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
  if (tabName) {
    $('#' + tabName).tab('show');
  }
  
  $('button[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('id'));
  });
});

Comment: could you post another question my friend